# Prove that an upper triangular matrix $A$, such that $A^*A = AA^*$, must be diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be an upper triangular matrix that satisfies $A^{*}A=AA^{*}$. Prove that $A$ must be diagonal.

My attempt is to partition $A$ as follows:

$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & \alpha\\
0 & \hat{A}\end{array}\right]
$$

where $\alpha = (a_{12}, a_{13}, \cdots , a_{1n})$ and $\hat{A}$ is $A$ with the first row and column removed. Using this partitioning, we have:

$$
A^{*}A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a_{11}^{2} & a_{11}\alpha\\
a_{11}\alpha^{*} & \alpha^{*}\alpha + \hat{A}^{*}\hat{A}\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
AA^{*} = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a_{11}^{2} + \alpha\alpha^{*} & \alpha\hat{A}^{*}\\
\hat{A}\alpha^{*} & \hat{A}\hat{A}^{*}\end{array}\right]
$$

Examining entry (1,1) of each of these matrix products, we see that $\alpha\alpha^{*} = 0$. From this, I would like to conclude that $\alpha = 0$ and thus, the first row of $A$ has non-zero entry only at (1,1). Then repeat this process continuously on $\hat{A}$.

However, I can see a flaw in my argument. If the entries of A were real, then this argument seems like it would work. But since the entries can be complex, this means that $\alpha\alpha^{*} = 0$ even with $\alpha \ne 0$. For example, $\alpha = (1, i, 1, i)$ gives $\alpha\alpha^{*} = 0$.

Any ideas how to proceed here? I know that with this partitioning, I must have $\alpha = 0$ since the problem statement is true (i.e. $A$ is diagonal).

Comment: $A^\ast$ denotes the *adjoint* (aka the *conjugate transpose*), not the straight-up transpose. Hence, in particular, since $\alpha$ is a complex row vector, $\alpha \alpha^\ast = \|\alpha\|^2$, where $\|v\| = \sqrt{|v_1|^2+\cdots+|v_n|^2}$ denotes the usual norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Note that "$*$" usually means not just transpose but *conjugate* transpose. So your counterexample isn't actually a counterexample. $\alpha\alpha^*$ is actually the squared norm of $\alpha$, and one of the properties of a norm is that $\|\alpha\|=0$ implies that $\alpha = 0$. So you actually have the right idea in your proof.

Comment: As the previous comment said, your proof is absolutely correct. Squirtle's prompt answer below was identical.

Answer (score 1):

First look at the first row $(i=1)$:

$$(AA^*)_{(1,:)}=\sum_{j} A_{1,j} \bar{A}_{j,1} = A_{1,1}\bar{A}_{1,1} + 0 + \cdots = A_{1,1}^2 = \sum_{j} \bar{A}_{j,1} A_{1,j} = (A^*A)_{(1,:)}$$

$$\iff$$

$$A_{1,j} = 0 \forall j\neq i(=1)$$

Repeat for every row, $i$.

QED

Comment: The equals sign at the very end is true a priori because we are assuming that $AA^*=A^*A$; this implies that the next to last equals sign must also be true. (i.e. c=e, e=f, implies c=f).

Answer (score 1):

Partition $A$ as
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12}\\0 & A_{22}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If $A$ is normal, then
$$
AA^* = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}A_{11}^* + A_{12}A_{12}^* & \star\\\star & \star \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}^*A_{11} & \star\\\star & \star \end{pmatrix} = A^*A,
$$
so $A_{11}^*A_{11} = A_{11}A_{11}^* + A_{12}A_{12}^*$. Now this means
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A_{11}^*A_{11})= \operatorname{tr}(A_{11}A_{11}^*)= \operatorname{tr}(A_{11}A_{11}^* + A_{12}A_{12}^*) = \operatorname{tr}(A_{11}A_{11}^*) + \operatorname{tr}(A_{12}A_{12}^*) \implies \operatorname{tr}(A_{12}A_{12}^*) = 0 \implies A_{12}=0.
$$
So now we have established that $A$ is block diagonal. Further, $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are normal. Proceed by induction on $A_{11},A_{22}$, and further blocks to conclude that $A$ is in fact diagonal.

Comment: Is reaching out for the trace really needed?
Your 3rd  equation line yields $A_{12}\left(A_{12}\right)^* = 0$ which is satisfied (if and) only if each entry in $A_{12}$ is zero.

Comment: @Hanno You've just made me realize that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The trace of $AA^*$ is $\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2$.

On the other hand, since $A$ commutes with $A^*$ it is *normal*, so unitarily diagonalizable, and the eigenvalues of $AA^*$ are the numbers $|\lambda|^2$ with $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$. Now $A$ is triangular, so the egienvalues of $A$ are the numbers $a_{1,1}$, $\dots$, $a_{n,n}$, and we see that the trace of $AA^*=\sum_i|a_{i,i}|^2$.

Comparing the two descriptions of the trace of $AA^*$ we see that $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: While correct, I would argue that this is not a "go to" proof, because the spectral theorem is itself proven based on the fact that a triangular normal matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. you are free to be wrong, of course :-) There is absolutely no need to base the proof of the spectral theorem on that, and that is actually very inconvenient. If $A$ is normal, then you can easily find a non-zero vector $v$ that is  an eigenvector for $A$ and for $A^*$, and the orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ is invariant under $A$ and $A^*$, so you can do induction there.

Comment: It's not about being right or wrong, it's about having a self-contained proof that does not rely on other results, except the assumption that $A$ is normal, which is not the case in your proof, hence why I don't consider it a "go to" :P And, while I concede that proving the spectral theorem does not need to go trough the usual Schur triangularization step, I do find this way of proving it extremely convenient and intuitive, and it seems that this is the go to proof in most textbooks, but I guess we can agree to disagree on this part.

Comment: That proof completely obscures the fact that the diagonalizability of normal maps entirely similar to that of unitary ones — the argument I sketched is **exactly** the same one that one uses for unitrary matrices, for which the fact $A$ shares with $A^*$ an eigenvector is more obvious.